# Prevent MS-Access from displaying or allowing user to go back to previous record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have an ms-access form in which the user enters assembly information (component serial numbers, measurements, print revision...etc)  I have the form set as:

```
Data Entry = Yes
Allow Additions = Yes
Allow Deletions = No
Allow Edits = No
Cycle = Current Record
```

However, I still can not achieve what I'm after which is, when a user enters the data and submits it (moves from the first record entered to the second), preventing the user from cycling back to the first record that was submitted unless the form is closed and re-opened.

Is there some way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `After Insert` event of the form and force a requery of the forms data there:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    Me.Requery
End Sub
```

That would assure that you never have the just added record in the record source and so can't move back to it.

Comment: Thank you.  It does exactly what I was looking for.